# An ODE I saw online - question about a couple of steps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I saw the following problem:

$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2}= \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{n}\ , n\ne 2$

and I was following through the steps and saw this:

let $p = \frac{dy}{dx}$ and therefore $\frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}$

The next step looked a bit odd to me. It was

$\frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{dp}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}= p\frac{dp}{dy}$ --> I just wasn't sure *quite* how you get there, and I wanted to be sure I didn't miss some elementary step. I'm sure it is probably obvious or some rule I forgot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $\underline{\textrm{chain rule}}$ has been applied. The derivative of $p(y(x))$ is $p'(y)\cdot y'(x)=\frac{dp}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: so we are looking at it as p multiplied by y(x) here? I thought that derivative would be p(y'(x)) + p'(y(x)) ? Or is it p as a function of y(x)?

Comment: Yes $p$ is a function of $y(x)$.

Comment: ok so if we take that derivative p from above and explicitly wrote it... I see -- thanks!